# A super strange bug of os.path.abspath

Tags: python, windows, filesystems

On My Python 2.6 ( 64bit, win7, ActivePython ),
when i call:
`os.path.abspath('D:/PROJECTS/SuiShouBei/www/ssb/static/voices/en/mp3/con.mp3')`

It returns:
`'\\\\.\\con'`

I have no problem with other paths so far.

Anyone has the same issue?
Can someone please tell me why?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I can reproduce this in Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.1 and 3.2.

The reason for this behavior is the fact that `CON` is an [illegal filename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Windows (try `os.path.abspath('D:/PROJECTS/SuiShouBei/www/ssb/static/voices/en/mp3/cont.mp3')` and see that everything works fine).

So take care that your filenames don't contain

```
< (less than)
> (greater than)
: (colon)
" (double quote)
/ (forward slash)
\ (backslash)
| (vertical bar or pipe)
? (question mark)
* (asterisk)
```

Also do not use the following reserved device names for the name of a file (with or without extension):

```
CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, 
LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9.
```

As noticed by slowdog, it is mentioned in [the same MSDN document as above](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#win32_device_namespaces) that `\\.\CON` is the correct way to access such a device name directly.

Comment: Tim, thank you for your answer. I googled 'con' and found no file can be named 'con.*', because it's a 'DEVICE NAME'. Shame on Windows.

Comment: Should not the function simply return 'CON' in this situation?

Comment: Hard to say what it *should* return if it encounters a filename that shouldn't even exist. You could also argue that it should have raised an exception.

Comment: shouldn't windows handle this and disallow any files trying to be saved as `con.*`? :/ Even any files coming in from another OS could be caught as they're being written locally

Comment: @Alex: What if you're plugging in an USB stick that was written on a Mac?

Comment: @Tim I was thinking of that...Guess it would try to open it, but only freak out if you tried to save it locally? Moot point I guess, just wondering.

Comment: @wberry: Apparently, '\\.\CON' is a (possible *the*) correct way to refer to the device: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#win32_device_namespaces

Comment: What do you mean "shame on windows"? It has to name its devices.

Comment: @David: Yeah, but I think it's not necessary to keep the device name under EVERY path

Comment: @Vergil It's a hangover from DOS where there were no paths.