# Remove all illegal characters

Tags: regex

Hi I'm new to regex so could anyone help me? I want to remove all illegal characters in a filename for windows. This is the regex I used

```
(/[^a-zA-Z ')' 0-9\\-]+/g,'')")
```

The problem is it's not getting rid of the brackets. For example the original filename was

```
[Yuubin Basha (Akizuki Ryou)] Cheap Thrill (Final Fantasy VII) [English] [Dragonfly]
```

and it renames to

```
Yuubin Basha Akizuki Ryou) Cheap Thrill Final Fantasy VII) English Dragonfly
```

It doesn't remove all the brackets. Can anyone help me fix my regex?

Comment: Brackets and parenthesis aren't invalid in a file name

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6984500/20670) - there are a lot more things to consider when checking for illegal filenames.

Comment: Also, brackets and parentheses are perfectly legal in a filename. I don't get it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/[^a-zA-Z\\)\\(\\]\\[0-9\\-\s]+/g
```

regex should look like in your case

Comment: But what if I want one that [JSLint thinks is okay](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3041666/1028230)? ;)  Also, the extra info from [the link in @Tim's comment, above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984450/a-super-strange-bug-of-os-path-abspath/6984500#6984500) is excellent showing checking for bad file names seems even more complicated.

Answer (score 5):

File names on Windows can contain all Unicode characters except U+0000 through U+001F and `:?*"\/<>|`. So you can use

```
[\x00-\x1f:?\\/*"<>|]
```

But there are other considerations as well, e.g. a file name cannot end with a space.

Answer (score 0):

Check it out `(/[^a-zA-Z ')' 0-9\\-]+/g,''\)")`